# Pusch screen onto a Modal or Fix Modal to a Specific Screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a stack of two screens : screen A + screen B.

Here is my scenario :

1. In screen A, I display a modal.
2. In this modal, I have a button that push screen B.
3. Screen B is pushed.

Everything "works" BUT screen B is pushed BEHIND the modal. I would like to fix the modal to the screen A to keep modal open when I goBack from screen B (So I don't want to hide modal before push screen B). OR, I want to push screen B ONTO modal.

I can't find any solution to do this but tiktok does it with comments : at the moment you clic on username of a comment a screen is pushed onto the comment view which seems to be a modal. I want to have the same result. Anyone have clues ?

(I checked screen transition but I can't find any way to push screen on modal.)

thanks you